# What is comparability in relations?

Tags: general-topology, logic, relations, order-theory

So I've just started trying to teach myself some topology and I've been reading through topology by munkres.
In the first chapter he defines order relations being a binary relation satisfying transitivity, nonreflexivity and comparability this has caused me a lot of confusion and I am struggling to grasp the concepts.

My main confusion is to do with that of comparability what exactly is it on Wikipedia the definition of a total  order (which is what munkres is talking about in his book) is a binary relation satisfying transitivity,antisymmetry and connexity.

my question is what is connexity is it the same as comparability and how are these 2 definitions equivalent?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are you getting the term "connexity" from? I don't think it appears in Munkres's book or in any relevant Wikipedia articles?

Comment: @rob arthan on Wikipedia if you search the definition of total order relation they use connexity

Comment: Please provide a link to justify your claim.

Comment: @RobArthan I assume they mean from here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order

Comment: @alexander tenenbaum yes thats the one thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference in definitions is that Wikipedia defines non-strict total orders (things like $x\le y$ where elements relate to themselves) and Munkres defines strict total orders (things like $x<y$ where elements do not relate to themselves). Wikipedia's connexity condition states that for any $x,y$ either $x\le y$ or $y\le x$. This is not true for strict total orders in the case where $x=y$, so Munkres' definition instead states for any **distinct** $x,y$ either $x<y$ or $y<x$. Annoyingly "total order" as used in math is ambiguous, we precede it by "strict" or "non-strict" if we want to distinguish which we are talking about.

For what it's worth "connex" is quite rare, I don't think I've ran into it outside Wikipedia. According to [this talk page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Total_order) it was introduced because the previous language (calling this a "total" relation) was ambiguous.